# Ruby Prolog interpreter

Tags: library, ruby

Is there a Prolog interpreter written in Ruby?

I've come to find [ruby-prolog](https://github.com/preston/ruby-prolog) and other such DSLs, but I am actually interested in a interpreter for the true Prolog language, similar to this [JS interpreter](https://curiosity-driven.org/prolog-interpreter).

In other words, I want something in Ruby that can read actual Prolog files.

Comment: https://github.com/cie/rubylog is a prolog interpreter written in ruby.

Comment: @thg Nice one, but it's not a true Prolog interpreter, but a Prolog-like DSL

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there's a complete implementation out there.

But I guess those projects are the *nearest* solutions you might find:

- https://github.com/ch1c0t/protagor/tree/master/lib/protagor
- https://github.com/ranxian/rprolog

depending on what you need you might make use of projects that connect to the traditional interpreters.

For example

- https://github.com/rickpr/prolegomenon
- https://github.com/jdallien/xsb-interface